# Apply GST in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, tax

I want to apply GST according to Product unit price and in case discount is applied hence GST is calculated on discounted amount.
For Intrastate(with in the state):

if unit price + discount  < Rs1000 : 5%  (2.5% CGST + 2.5% SGST)

if unit price + discount  > Rs1000 : 12% (6% CGST + 6% SGST)

For Interstate:

if unit price + discount <1000 : 5%  (IGST)

if unit price + discount  >1000 : 12% (IGST)
[image]

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: This extension has the feature you are looking for
https://magecomp.com/magento-indian-gst.html

Comment: Hi, my simple solution, hire PHP developer, they give a complete solution. This is your payment related stuff, be aware.

Comment: @user00247 did you get a solution for this? i have also a same requirement

Answer (score 1):

[Please check this blog](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/)

Try to edit the logic as per your need. Create system config values in admin panel for CGST, SGST, IGST percentage values. Get those inside the collect function and calculate the tax and modify the total.

Answer (score 0):

Credits  : [Magecomp link](https://magecomp.com/blog/create-gst-tax-rule-magento/)

To bifurcate **GST** taxes to show separately in all the order related documents, go to

go to and copy `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\tax\order\tax.phtml`

```
<?php if ($isFirst): ?>
                <td <?php echo $this->getValueProperties()?> rowspan=" 1 <?php echo count($rates); ?>">
                    <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($amount); ?>
                </td>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

and paste at `app\design\frontend\[theme_package]\template\tax\order` And replace code as shown below:

```
<?php //if ($isFirst): ?>
                <td <?php echo $this->getValueProperties()?> rowspan=" 1 <?php //echo count($rates); ?>">
                    <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($amount / ($percent/(float)$rate['percent']) ); ?>
                </td>
            <?php //endif; ?>
```

Now you can see you can see the detailed tax charges with the bifurcation of **SGST and CGS**T taxes in **cart, checkout, invoice, credit memo, shipment, my account order view and Emails.**

**Result** :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> $itemAfterDiscountPrice= ($item->getPrice() *
>   $item->getDiscountPercent())/100 ;
>   $prdPrice=$item->getPrice()-$itemPriceAfterDiscount;

You can get after discount price in this way and set condition as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have tried the same but Not getting the result with SGST and CGST separately  and the template file is

> frontend/base/default/template/tax/checkout/tax.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Magento GST India extension by Meetanshi allows setting minimum product price to apply set GST rate and set another GST rate for the product prices below minimum set price.

[image: Magento GST India Extension by Meetanshi]

To fulfill your requirement, you can get and configure the extension as below:

GST Rate = 12%
minimum product price amount to apply above GST rate = 1000

And GST rate to apply on products below minimum set price = 5%

Visit https://meetanshi.com/magento-gst-india.html to check the live demo and get the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this article step by step to setup GST in Magento 2.
http://www.credevator.com/how-to-configure-gst-in-magento-2/